# Is a revision of the std::allocator interface planned for future C++ versions?

Tags: c++, c++20, allocator, c++-concepts, c++23

In [a talk from 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U) Andrei Alexandrescu outlines some atrocities of the std::allocator interface, shortly highlighting how it's not in fact about allocation and proposing a different way of thinking about these allocators that would make them more usable and modular. Or, to quote from the description:

> std::allocator has an inglorious past, murky present, and cheerless future. STL introduced allocators as a stop gap for the now antiquated segmented memory models of the 1990s. Their design was limited and in many ways wasn't even aiming at helping allocation that much. Because allocators were there, they simply continued being there, up to the point they became impossible to either uproot or make work, in spite of valiant effort spent by the community.

> This talk discusses the full design of a memory allocator created from first principles. It is generic, componentized, and composable for supporting application-specific allocation patterns.

His main points against the current std::allocator are contained in [this section](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?t=1097) of the video, but to summarize:

1. Allocators should not care about the type being allocated, only the size and alignment.
2. Allocators should not be responsible for storing size information about an allocation, allocation and deallocation should symmetrically (respectively) return and receive a `Blk` (ptr, size).
3. `Rebind<U>::other` is terrible (he did not go in further detail)
4. Allocators should not be stateless (since they literally give you pieces of memory, how can they be stateless?)
5. Allocators should be defined around the concept of composition; if you look at real world allocators they are all composed of small little allocators that conditionally run.

Ever since I watched that talk I have expected some kind of proposal to follow from it, since the idea seemed so sound and usable. I've had to work with std::allocator in the past and it made me understand the need for C++20 concepts for the first time when my screen screamed at me in *candidate function not viable*.

But nothing seems to have come from it? I wasn't around back then but it seems like STL2 was in the works, but that has since been discontinued. Has it been decided somewhere that concepts would be sufficient to at least mediate the symptoms of std::allocator (if so, where/when?) or is it a backwards-compatibility problem? Is something related to this on the roadmap for a future C++ version?

Comment: can you elaborate on *it's not in fact about allocation* and what you want it look like?

Comment: The original reason to include it in the STL was apparently to deal with the problem of near/far pointers: [this section](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?t=868) of the talk highlights the main problems with std::allocator, and the rest of it outlines a new design. He basically proposes to use small composable predefined allocators like 'segrator', 'stackallocator', 'nullallocator', 'fallbackallocator' and use composition to build a complex, custom allocator for a certain application from that.

Comment: Actually, [this section](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?t=1097) a bit later gives a better summary.

Comment: I do not want to look at a a long presentation. Could you summarize the problems with the current allocator interface?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I updated the question with a short summary. I do recommend you watch it sometime though, for me it was very insightful!

Comment: Only my opinion, but the fact for the standard containers not to be inheritable is much more a problem than the allocators. In the opposite, the Java or Python standard libraries provide interfaces or base classes that programmers can use to build custom containers. I once tried to build a container for wrapping 2D plain arrays in the way `vector` wraps 1D array, pulled off my hairs during some time and finally gave up.

Comment: What do you mean not inheritable, as in their member functions aren't virtual?

Comment: I'm looking at your points, and most of them are "meh, who cares" or "really, you pass the size to deallocate".  Have you worked with C++17 and above allocators?  Much of the cruft is just gone.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, my last experience with them was not in C++17 I believe, I will have to look into it again in the future. The introduction of std::allocator_traits seems more like a patch to something more deeply broken than a fundamental fix though

Answer (score 3):

There is no proposal for a radical re-alteration of the allocator model. This is for basically two reasons.

The C++ container library relies on allocators working a certain way, and it would be complex in the extreme to make containers that work with both kinds of allocators. So if you want a new allocator model, you're also talking about a new set of containers, which is a *huge* can of worms that the committee balked at opening.

Most of the deficiencies in allocator creation and usage are pretty avoidable these days. Writing an allocator even in C++17 is not exactly a challenge. You don't need to understand the gory details of the thing; you just need to implement a couple of functions and a few member aliases. `std::allocator_traits` fills in most of the blanks for you.

At the end of the day, there are significant deficiencies in the C++ language and library that are more important than an allocator model that's more difficult to use than is strictly necessary.

Comment: Was this discussion about it in the committee documented somewhere?

Comment: @AdriaanJacobs: There was never a proposal on the subject, so there wasn't something for the committee to discuss. I'm explaining why such a thing was never proposed and would likely not be accepted.

Comment: I thought because you said _the committee balked at opening this huge can of worms_ this was in reference to something you had read. Also, don't you think a subset of Andrei's proposals could be implemented under the current std::allocator interface? Predefining a couple of classes that satisfy the Allocator requirements and that are modular like Andrei suggests?

Answer (score 0):

We already have `std::pmr` built on top of allocators that addresses all listed concerns.